# grep displaying also results which are 1 character off?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, search

I often have a typo in my grep searches, especially when it comes to long names. So for instance,

```
grep "super_duper_utralong_name" *txt
```

would normally not contain `super_duper_ultralong_name` (notice ultra vs utra) as a result. But that is exactly what I wish to achieve.

How I can I do that? Preferably even within a regex like `super_duper_[:alpha:]*_name`. Whether it's grep or some other grep-like tool, matters little.

Comment: grep "super_.*" or egrep "super_.*|.*_duper_.*|.*name" The possible combinations are infinite. Just look at `man grep` /reg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Approximate Grep (`agrep`) with the `-#` flag, where `#` is the number of mismatches allowed.

```
$ agrep    "super_duper_utralong_name" <<< super_duper_ultralong_name
$ agrep -1 "super_duper_utralong_name" <<< super_duper_ultralong_name
super_duper_ultralong_name
```

See [Agrep's manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/agrep.1.html) for further options.